# Is it possible that I have deleted some commands in my terminal?

Tags: terminal, command

I have been trying to install flutter on my Mac. At some point I must have changed the path of a couple of commands in the terminal.
For example, I can't use vim, git, curl etc. ... It says "zsh: command not found:"

What can I do?

Comment: Why you changed the path of commands. If you want to use same command from diffnt path then you can create symbolic link of the original command to a new path.

Comment: and yes you can delete any command from /usr/bin . But be aware of what you really deleting else you can't login back after restart your machine.